# Is there a way to modularize parameter preparation with Bicep?

Tags: azure-bicep

We have a bunch of naming- and ip-rules with a lot of resource groups to be created for dev, test and production. Because of the rules, we can calculate the names and ip ranges from two parameters: the stage to deploy to and the name of the service implemented by the resource group.

Example:

- a service named "calculator" that includes a storage account and a vnet for stage "test" in a resource group
- using

  - azure naming conventions
  - "xyz" as the abbreviation for our company
  - service name
  - additional specifier
  - 10.1.0.0/16 for TEST
  - 10.x.2.0/24 for "calculator"
- we get:

  - resource group "rg-calculator-test"
  - storage account name = saxyzcalculatortest001
  - vnet = vnet-xyz-calculator-test 10.1.2.0/24
  - sub net 1 name = snet-xyz-calculator-test 10.1.2.0/26
  - sub net 2 name = snet-xyz-calculator-test-pep 10.1.2.128/28

To enforce consistency, I would like to share the calculation of all such names and addresses between all resource group deployment scripts.

Is there a way similar to "class files" or "includes" that I can use to include such a variable calculation into multiple .bicep files, so that I only need to pass a minimum set of variables (service name + stage) and the rest can be calculated in a consistent way without massive copy and paste of all those "var ... = ((stage == 'dev') ? '...' : (stage == 'test') ? '...' : '...')"?

I already did serch the documentation (maybe I simply did not recognize the Bicep-"thing" that can modularize the scripts in a way I need). What I was expecting was some synthak like

```
method CalculateDefaults 'modules/calculateDefaults.bicep' = {
  name: 'CalculateDefaults'
  params: {
    stage: stage
    serviceName: 'Calculator'
  }
}
```

which produces outputs that I can use like

```
resource virtualNetwork 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks@2021-02-01' = {
  name: virtual_network_name
  location: location
  tags: tags
  properties: {
    addressSpace: {
      addressPrefixes: [
        CalculateDefaults.outputs.vnet_address_prefix
      ]
    }
```

Comment: the vnet/subnet address space length is always the same in each env ? could you explain a bit more on the calculation you are trying to do please ?

Comment: @Thomas
I've accomplished "some" of my goals: I currently can calculate the network addresses by calling a "module". For this I have a convention to always have a /24 vnet, a /26 default subnet, a /28 private-endpoint subnet.
What still is problematic in my opinion: the names of the resources cannot be concatenated from results of a "sub-module" - they need to be generated before deploying a module, so they cannot be the result of a sub-deployment. Because of that, I still need a huge amount of parameters for each and every module ... not so great. Something reusable would be much better.

Comment: not sure to understand why you need a module? You could always use variables to concatenate/calculate everything in the same module/file ? Would you be able to share your bicep files please ?